# Is reinterpreting a member function pointer a 'good idea'?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, reinterpret-cast

I have a worker thread, which holds a list of 'Thread Actions', and works through them as an when.

```
template <class T> class ThreadAction
{
public:

  typedef void (T::*action)();

  ThreadAction(T* t, action f) :
    func(f),obj(t) {}
  void operator()() { (obj->*func)(); }

  void (T::*func)();
  T* obj;

};
```

It's normally called like this

```
myActionThread->addAction(
    new ThreadAction<TheirClass>(this, &TheirClass::enable)
);
```

Which worked fine until

```
 void TheirClass::enable()
```

was changed to

```
 bool TheirClass::enable()
```

Sadly we can't change it back again because other stuff needs the new format, (and overloads can't differ by return type alone).

I did try

```
myActionThread->addAction( 
    new ThreadAction<TheirClass>(this, 
        reinterpret_cast<void(TheirClass::*)>(&TheirClass::enable)
    )
);
```

Which appears to work just fine, but I'm not certain that reinterpreting a function pointer like this is 'defined' behaviour, can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely *not* supported behavior, and can potentially cause your program to crash.

Basically, you need to make a wrapper for `TheirClass::enable()` that will have the proper return type. A simple one-liner will suffice:

```
public:
    void enableWrapper() { enable(); };
```

Then call:

```
myActionThread->addAction(
    new ThreadAction<TheirClass>(this, &TheirClass::enableWrapper)
);
```

If you can't modify `TheirClass` directly, then create a simple subclass or helper class that implements the wrapper.

Comment: Reinterpreting member function pointers is particularly bad because their size can vary depending on the class: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Err, from what I've understood, you're casting from a method that returns a `bool` to a method that returns `void` ?

This may be dangerous, depending on the calling/returning convention in use. You *might* forget to pop the return value - or override the value of a register with the return value.

Comment: +1 Good point about overwriting a register with the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea.  Consider adding an additional template parameter for return type:

```
template <class T, typename RetType> class ThreadAction
{
public:
 typedef RetType (T::*action)();
 ThreadAction(T* t, action f) :
   func(f),obj(t) {}

 RetType operator()() { return (obj->*func)(); }
 RetType (T::*func)();
 T* obj;
};
```

This is an application of [return void](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2008/07/return-void.html).

Comment: In typedef, void need to change to RetType

Answer (score 1):

I generally find that when the question is of the form "Is _______ a good idea?" the answer is almost invariably "NO!"

This is probably true without context.